# Передать HTTP-запрос от Nginx к PHP

Tags: php, nginx, http, сокет, веб-сервер

Nginx слушает 80 порт, я хочу чтобы при запросе к `example.com/tophp` Nginx не обрабатывал его, а передал дальше **консольному**  приложению на PHP (CLI).

Т.е. php тоже должен слушать, наверно, 80 порт, как-то через сокеты (я, вообще, в этой теме ничего не знаю).

Может какое-то проксирование делается на Nginx, типа на php поднят веб-сервер, который слушает 79 порт, а nginx проксирует к нему. Лучше, конечно, чтобы nginx вообще не обрабатывал 80 порт `example.com/tophp`, чтобы запрос сразу шел к php. Как получится.

Пример:

Php скрипт работает вечным циклом, ждет запроса.

...Идет запрос на `http://example.com/test`. Nginx обрабатывает его, php скрипт ничего не получает.

...Идет запрос на `http://example.com/tophp`. Nginx не обрабатывает его, а передает его **КОНСОЛЬНОМУ** PHP cli скрипту. И дальше уже в php в бексконечном цикле обрабатывается этот запрос, как я хочу.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это вообще реализуется?

Comment: в бесконечном цикле совсем не нужно. да и никто не даст вам такое делать, только сокеты, а не http

Comment: @jashka почему в бесконечном цикле не нужно? Скрипт должен работать всегда - принял запрос, обработал, принимает дальше. Плюс по мимо принятия запроса в цикле выполняются свои действия

Answer (score 2):

1. Что такое *консольное PHP приложение*. Это то, что выполняется в консоли/терминале, например:

   php app/console YOU_COMMAND

по сути это bash скрипт, который вызывает определённый скрипт написанный уже на php. То есть по запросу вам необходимо выполнять bash скрипт. Для этого в NGINX необходимо установить модуль [lua](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/modules/lua/). А в конфиге должно быть что то такое:

```
location /tophp  {
  content_by_lua 'os.execute("/bin/tophp.sh")';
}
```

2. Тот же консольный php скрипт можно выполнить средствами php. Вы обращаетесь по url, а php делает через [shell_exec](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.shell-exec.php)/[exec](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.exec.php) что то типа:

`shell_exec("php -n -s $File");`

> shell_exec - функция идентична оператору обратный апостроф.

То есть выражение можно записать так:

```
`php -n -s $File`
```

3. Зачем выполнять php из под консоли если можно его выполнить без консоли :)

   PHP cli == php

Просто создайте контроллер который будет выполнять ровно то что в php cli или вызывать ту функцию, которая в php cli

4. Работа в вечном цикле. Вся суть php в том, что он после выполнения запроса "затухает". После выполнения скрипта php ложится спать. И если у Вас вся работа построена на вечном цикле над правильностью этого решения стоит задуматься. PHP может работать фоново:

   ignore_user_abort(1);
   set_time_limit(0);

Можно сделать [демон](http://mithrandir.ru/professional/php/php-daemons.html) на php.

Но фоновый режим php это напоминает костыль-затычку в поиске быстрого решения, а демон на php должен запускаться из под консоли, а не по ссылке, потому что каждый раз когда Вы запускаете демон Вы порождаете новый процесс, который находится в вечном цикле.

---

Вы писали:

> Скрипт должен работать всегда - принял запрос, обработал, принимает дальше.

Тогда он вечно не должен крутиться. По урлу он опять запустится без всякого цикла

Answer (score 0):

В вашем случае, я могу только посоветовать почитать это: [nginx Rewrite Rules](https://www.nginx.com/blog/creating-nginx-rewrite-rules/)

Ну а вообще просто нужно сделать необходимый rewrite похожий на этот:

```
rewrite ^/listings/(.*)$ /listing.html?listing=$1 last;
```

Comment: rewrite тут не поможет.